How to create a fixed position listing for featured and organic products in app like OLX?

I wanted to structure it as shown in the image after searched some product, but at the same time, I want the main focus to be on newly added products. I want this to be the case on each page. If there are no featured products left when moving to the next page, it should bring the featured product from the previous page.until there is no more featured product left on every page
class Product(BaseModel):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        APPROVED = 'approved', 'APPROVED'
        WAITING  = 'waiting' ,  'WAITING',
        REJECTED = 'refected', 'REJECTED'
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'account.Account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name=_("Owner"),
        )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        help_text=_("User-friendly attribute name"),
        verbose_name=_("Name"),
        )
    
    web_id = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, max_length=5)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
        help_text=_("Short attribute label"),
        verbose_name=_("Slug"),
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'tag_map.Category',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name=_("Category of product"),
    )

    content  = RichTextUploadingField(
        blank=True,
        default="",
        help_text=_("Short description"),
        verbose_name=_("Description"),
    )

    location = models.ForeignKey(
        'tag_map.Location',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    rank        = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

class Tariff(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Tariff Name'))
    duration_in_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Duration in Days')
    duration_in_hours = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Duration in Hours")
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.duration_in_days} days, {self.duration_in_hours} hours) -- {self.price} uzs"

    def total_duration(self):
        return timedelta(days=self.duration_in_days, hours=self.duration_in_hours)

class FeaturedProduct(BaseModel):

    product = models.OneToOneField(
        'product.Product', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='featureds',
        verbose_name=_("Product"))
    
    tariff = models.ForeignKey(
        'product.Tariff', 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name="Tariff"
    )

    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name="Start Time")
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="End Time")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.title} (Featured until {self.end_time})"
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.end_time:
            self.end_time = self.start_time + self.tariff.total_duration()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def is_active(self):
        return now() <= self.end_time

this is my model

I'm finding it hard to edit your codes... Please edit your codes with each line starting on a new line.

Next time, try to be a bit more responsive with your first question...

You can use itertools.groupby(…) [python-doc] to post-process the query:
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, v in groupby(
        Product.objects.order_by('is_featured'), attrgetter('groupby')
    )
}
This will make one query, and will generate a dictionary where the value of is_featured is mapped to a list of Product items.

I want to add 2 featured and 8 organic products on one page. In general, is it correct to divide them into two groups, bring them in, and then set the correct position for each?

For that you can use a .union(…) [Django-doc]:
Product.objects.filter(is_featured=True)[:2].union(
    Product.objects.filter(is_featured=False)[:8],
    all=True
)

it is giving me this error     raise DatabaseError(
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: LIMIT/OFFSET not allowed in subqueries of compound statements. and also if I do pagination with this query does this work properly?

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: well,do you use it as subquery?

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: as of the pagination, how would you paginate a set that contains 2 this and 8 that? Then there are ten items, so you make at most ten pages with one item.

I just want, in every page should have 10 product: 2 featured and 8 organic you can take look olx website I just want like this

yes I use it as subquery

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: Subquerys in Django can only work with one record and one value, so not a set of items.

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: I think however if you want to obtain a helpful answer, you probably should explain the full problem (edit the question and explain what you want to achieve, not how you want to achieve it).

I edited and  I tried my best to explain I hope you can answer
